# Will I be able to use gnome-session-fallback with 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, gnome-classic

I am a passionate hater of unity (sorry) and the first thing I did last time with 12.04 was install gnome-session-fallback to get the layout I wanted.

Now I am going to get a new computer soon and want to use the 14.04 for the long term support. However unity is a deal-breaker for me, I will go with Mint before I will put up with unity.

So, the big question is, will gnome-session-fallback be usable with 14.04? I would assume I can (exactly why is the leadership trying to limit my choices?), but this page worries me, as it states the package was removed in 14.04: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/proposed/gnome-session-fallback

Will I be able to use gnome-session-fallback in Trusty (and presumably later releases)?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `gnome-session-fallback` is still [present](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gnome-session-fallback) in the official repositories. `gnome-session-fallback` is now a meta package that installs `gnome-session-flashback`, which provides the same functionality. It should work as you expect.

Comment: Great its good to know. I will be waiting til the 17th then, and installing directly. Looking forward to this!

Answer (score 1):

If you like pure GNOME, why not directly install [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org/)? Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 has being granted [LTS status](http://ubuntugnome.org/lts-status/) and has an [active mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-gnome/2014-March/date.html) for you to interact with other users and developers.

Comment: Ah that's an option I didn't consider, I will look into it. Thanks!